# How to display only "after now" dates (of multiple) of a date-field in a node?

Tags: theming, datetime

I have an 'event' node-type with just a body and a date-field. For that date-field, multiple dates are allowed.

I'm listing event-nodes in a view and already use filters to only display nodes when the latest date is after 'now', so that completely outdated events do not get listed automatically. However, when I have multiple dates and at least one of those is still in the future, the node gets displayed.

In the latter case, **how can hide all dates that are in the past, and only display the ones that are still in the future**? I didn't find an option for that for the date-field in the node-type display settings.

I guess I could override my `node.tpl.php` with a custom `node--event.tpl.php`, but how do I parse out single dates of my date-field then, check if they are in the past and hide those that are? I'm totally lost when it comes to PHP and Drupal content-arrays.. I'd appreciate any help with that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I dived into the drupal variables with the help of the devel module and came up with a solution (*first version, see better version below the edit*):

I now parsing all dates directly from the content in my specific `node--event.tpl.php`. I then iterate through them and store all dates that are in the past in a new array. In the end, if that array contains any values and my new option is activated (differentiating between teaser and full display), I remove those past-dates from the date-field array in the content:

```
<?php
// remove dates in the past from the date-field if enabled
if (isset($node->field_hide_past_dates) && !empty($node->field_hide_past_dates)) {
  $option = $node->field_hide_past_dates['und'][0]['value'];
  if (($option == "teaser" && $teaser) || $option == "always") {
    $UTC = new DateTimeZone("UTC");
    $now_utc_datetime = new DateTime( "now", $UTC );
    $past_date_array = array();
    foreach($content['field_eventdate']['#items'] AS $date_array) {
      $to_date_utc_string = $date_array['value2'];
      $to_date_utc_datetime = date_create_from_format("Y-m-d H:i:s", $to_date_utc_string, $UTC);
      if ($to_date_utc_datetime < $now_utc_datetime) {
        array_push($past_date_array, $date_array);
      }
    }

    if (count($past_date_array) > 0) {
      $only_future_date_array = array_filter($content['field_eventdate']['#items'], function ($var) use ($past_date_array) {
        return !in_array($var, $past_date_array);
      });
      $content['field_eventdate']['#items'] = $only_future_date_array;
    }
  }
}
?>
```

Maybe there is a cleaner way of preprocessing the content (let me know), but this was the quickest I could come up with and I now have the option per-node.

**== EDIT ==**

Why make it complicated: I forgot about hiding fields, so no more array-assigning, just on-the-fly hiding of past-dates:

```
if (isset($node->field_hide_past_dates) && !empty($node->field_hide_past_dates)) {
  $option = $node->field_hide_past_dates['und'][0]['value'];
  if (($option == "teaser" && $teaser) || $option == "always") {
    $UTC = new DateTimeZone("UTC");
    $now_utc_datetime = new DateTime( "now", $UTC );
    foreach($content['field_eventdate']['#items'] AS $key =>  $date_array) {
      $to_date_utc_string = $date_array['value2'];
      $to_date_utc_datetime = date_create_from_format("Y-m-d H:i:s", $to_date_utc_string, $UTC);
      if ($to_date_utc_datetime < $now_utc_datetime) {
        hide($content['field_eventdate'][$key]);
      }
    }
  }
}
```